# Usefulness of Synergy Enchantment

Tags: magic, medieval, low-fantasy

I have recently conceived of a fifth member of the Little Four, the four most common monsters in my fantasy world: Bitbugs. These cute little bugs have rounded bodies (they look sort of like blimps), big eyes and mouths, and pudgy stump-like legs. Think Kirby in insect form.

However, like all monsters, Bitbugs enchant whatever living thing or item kills them (within reason; more on that below). Their death effect (or the enchantment resulting from killing a Bitbug) is **Synergy.** You see, every Bitbug is just part of a whole, a single piece of something greater: the Bithive. The Bithive comprises a Bitbearer (the Queen) and the Bitbugs she bears (the Queen's children).

Since the Bitbearer is born from a Bitblotch (a fleshy structure born from the ground when chaos magic penetrates it, basically a tumor of reality), and the resulting Bithive is connected by the Bitblotch's energies, killing a Bitbug with something links that something to the Bithive. For example, if a sword is used to kill a Bitbug, it will then "sync" with and become an extension of the Bithive, gaining a life of its own and the ability to move at the cost of being essentially born a slave of the Bitbearer.

A similar effect happens to any living thing that kills a Bitbug; they become a subservient member of the Bithive, investing all of their talent, energy, and even life to defending and supporting the Bithive. There are two different kinds of Synergy for living things, Martial and Regal, one gained by killing a regular Bitbug with one natural weaponry (Ex: fangs and claws), the other gained by killing the Bitbearer herself, with or without a weapon. Regal Synergy can only be gained by females.

Creatures enchanted by Martial Synergy become stronger, faster, and tougher, gaining chitin armor and enhanced natural weaponry. They are then called Soldiers.
Creatures enchanted by Regal Synergy become the prime version of themselves (albeit with chitin armor and some other insect features) and gain both the capability to control anyone or anything under Martial Synergy (specifically, Synergy from Bitbugs born of the Bitbearer that you slew to gain Regal Synergy) and the ability to Spawn Bitborn, an unnatural fusion of Bitbug and whatever species the enchanted creature is. These lucky creatures are called Queens.

**Summary-TL;DR:**
Bitbugs are essentially Kirby in insect form, and they are born from a Bitbearer, which in turn is born from a Bitblotch, a sort of tumor born when chaos magic not only warps but *infects* (read: possesses) part of reality.

If an item is used to kill a Bitbug, it will gain life and the ability to move, becoming a new member of the Bithive (Bitbug collective; there are many separate collectives, each born of a different spot where chaos has infected this world).

If a creature kills a Bitbug with its natural weaponry or eats a Bitbug, it will become a subservient member of that Bitbug's Bithive, gaining chitin and enhanced natural weaponry and becoming stronger, faster and tougher to boot. This peculiar effect is an enchantment called **Martial Synergy**, and those holding it are called Soldiers.

If a female creature kills or eats a Bitbug Queen, or Bitbearer, it will become the best possible version of itself and gain three things: 1. chitin armor (and other insectoid features, like antennae and wings),
2. membership in and control of that Bitbearer's Hive, and 3. the ability to spawn Bitborn, which are a fusion of Bitbug and whatever species the Bitbearer's slayer is. This enchantment is called **Regal Synergy**, and those holding it are called Queens.

My question is, **How Useful Would This Be To Humans?**

-**Specifications:**

1. Please assume that said humans live in a typical medieval low-fantasy world. If that isn't clear enough, let me know and I'll be more specific.
2. Since a Bitbearer is aware of Synergy, it seems that she would order Bitbugs to seek out and get eaten by dangerous animals so she can better defend herself. This would seem to make it *very* difficult to reach the Bitbearer in order to gain Regal Synergy, the only obviously useful version of Synergy, unless one is a necromancer (has the advantage of sheer numbers) or a dragon (has the advantage of SHEER POWAH!), or unless someone predicts the appearance of a Bitblotch and kills the Bitbearer as she emerges.

The last one would be difficult, but for the sake of the question, let's say that there are crystals one can use to divine the location of a future (or present) Bitblotch, like a divination rod, but that Bitblotches only show up in remote and hazardous locations, like a deep cavern, a barren island, or inside an active volcano. (Bitbugs are born of chaos, so they are of course adapted to or in other words, immune to the hazardous locations of their Bitblotch.

3. I'm looking for ways humans can somehow turn Synergy to their benefit since it seems like a significant detriment. To make this clearer, each and every Bitbearer causes destruction and chaos in the area around their Blotch, since areas successfully overcome by discord in this way are infected by the Bitblotch, therefore spreading it.
4. A human with Regal Synergy has control over the Bithive 24/7, a human with Martial Synergy is under control 24/7.

Comment: i have a question, does the human still have control when not directly needed? or it under control 100% of the time?

Comment: @Topcode: A human with Regal Synergy has control over the Bithive 24/7, a human with Martial Synergy is under control 24/7.

Comment: ah, my answer doesn't work then

Comment: Ooooo noooo magical girls oooohhhh frrrriiiccckk

Comment: @Writer-of-stories: what's your problem with magical girls? Please explain, I'm quite curious.

Comment: The problem is, it usually turns into either fanservice and is then justified with bad answers. "Women are the only magicians." But why? Fanservice. This is an accidental example of that principle... the armor would make wearing clothes difficult. Plus, it's more fun if it's "You have to find one that matches your gender" instead of "I'm the queen. I respect your decisions, but if you have traditional magical girls, please make it gender nonspecific.

Comment: @Writer-of-stories: thank you for explaining your reasoning, I'll make Bitblades as counterparts to Bitbearers then.

Comment: Thank you. That helps and makes it more original. Although, I am curious. Why Bitblades? Commanders, not kings?

Comment: @Writer-of-stories: the reasoning behind the name Bitblade is because while mothers are perfectly capable of defending their children, I believe men are kind of meant to protect their loved ones. Therefore, since Bitblades are the male equivalent of Bitbearers....

Comment: Ahhhh. Even magic beast's namings are sexist.(its fine, helps make it realistically medival to have sexism sprinkled in.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Validation**.  Medieval humans are backward and cruel.  But if you show you've become the Queen you'll never hear that trash about "really being a man" again!

**Volcano preparedness**.  Toss in a Bitbug from far, far away and watch your problem shuffle off into the sunset.

**Vengeance**.  Make a deal with the Queen to give up the miseries of your daily struggle with your sorrowful heart, in exchange for her promise *your own* hands (or claws) will snuff out the one who killed your beloved.

**Vows**.  Your abbotess promises you will be able to serve perfectly in the rituals of your religion under her gentle command, accomplishing a sinless life in preparation for the hereafter.

**Vendetta**.  That malignant Queen must have to take a *little* time thinking about each of her servants.  And you have a thousand rounds of bird shot to clean up the neighborhood.

**Volatility**.  Burn a bug, awaken the fire!  It will devote all its time to defending and supporting the hive, so if the hive is under attack, it should go home to defend it, right?

**da Vinci**.  Further research is needed.  If you fire one of the Bitbugs from a trebuchet, does the trebuchet get enchanted, or the enemy city wall?  If you tie one up in a leather purse and bury it under a road, will the purse come to life, or the wagon that runs over it?

Comment: Shoo, I didn't think of anything like this! You covered society, religion, and pyromania all in one question, and even referenced the titans from Hercules! +1 for that.

Comment: But I didn't figure out a way to work in Bonzo's cup of tea. :(

Comment: That's perfectly fine, I don't even know that reference!

Comment: force feeding bitbugs to sick/plagued targets to get rid of them and spread disease among the hive? profit!